# Raspberry Pi Pico - Micropython - Get/Set mode of IO-Pin

Tags: micropython, raspberry-pi-pico

Is there a way to get/set the mode of a Pin object in MicroPython on the Raspberry Pi Pico?

The standard library has a [Pin.mode()](https://docs.micropython.org/en/latest/library/machine.Pin.html#machine.Pin.mode) function, but it is not supported on the Pi Pico.
Is there a way to directly change/get the mode of a pin instance?

The only workaround for at least reading the pin mode I came up with is using a regular expression:

```
import re
from machine import Pin


def is_input(pin: Pin):
    """
    Returns True, if the pin object's mode is set as INPUT, else False.
    """
    return re.search(r'mode=(\w*)', str(pin)).group(1) == 'IN'


p = Pin(0, Pin.IN)
print(is_input(p)) #True
p = Pin(0, Pin.OUT)
print(is_input(p)) #False
```

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a wrapper class to around the `machine.Pin` class which keeps track of the mode and pull setting and allows to change their values by re-initializing the underlying `machine.Pin` instance.

```py
import machine.Pin

class Pin:
    """
    Wrapper around machine.Pin which keeps track of mode and pull settings.
    """
    
    def __init__(self, id, mode=machine.Pin.IN, pull=None, **kwargs):
        """
        :param id: GPIO number of the Pin 
        :param mode: GPIO mode. Either machine.Pin.IN or machine.Pin.OUT; Defaults to machine.Pin.IN
        :param pull: GPIO pu/pd. Either machine.Pin.PULL_UP, machine.Pin.PULL_DOWN, None; Default to None
        :param kwargs: optional kw-only arguments for machine.Pin constructor
        """
        
        self._mode = mode
        self._pull = pull
        self._id = id
        self._pin = machine.Pin(id, mode=mode, pull=pull, **kwargs)

    def __getattr__(self, item):
        if item != '_pin':
            return getattr(self._pin, item)

    def __setattr__(self, key, value):
        if not hasattr(self, key) and hasattr(self._pin, key):
            setattr(self._pin, key, value)
        else:
            super().__setattr__(key, value)

    def mode(self, mode=None):
        """
        Get/set pin mode (input/output) by re-initializing pin.

        :param mode: Either machine.Pin.IN or machine.Pin.OUT
        :return: returns the current mode (machine.Pin.IN or machine.Pin.OUT) if mode was not provided.
        """

        if mode is None:
            return self._mode
        else:
            self._pin = machine.Pin(self._id, mode=mode, pull=self._pull)
            self._mode = mode

    def pull(self, pull=None):
        """
        Get/set pin pull-up/pull-down by re-initializing pin.

        :param pull: machine.Pin.PULL_UP, machine.Pin.PULL_DOWN, None
        :return: returns the current pull setting (machine.Pin.PULL_UP, machine.Pin.PULL_DOWN, None) if pull was not \
        provided.
        """
        
        if pull is None:
            return self._pull
        else:
            self._pin = machine.Pin(self._id, mode=self._mode, pull=pull)
            self._pull = pull
```